# Docker compile python file in Dockerfile don't create pyc

Tags: python, docker, docker-build, pyc

I would compile my python file (.py) in Dockerfile for create pyc file and then delete all *.py.

I create a Dockerfile like tisone:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
EXPOSE 8000
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

VOLUME /var/lib/cathstudio/data
WORKDIR /var/lib/cathstudio/data

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
#ENV PYTHONPATH /var/lib/cathstudio/data

COPY . /var/lib/cathstudio/data

RUN python -m compileall ajaxfuncs/
```

well, when i build my image compilation seems to be done:

[image]

but when i browse my file in volumes no pyc file are present:

[image]

How can i compile my python file during docker build for having the pyc s?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: They are compiled, you will find your compiled files inside the ```__pycache__``` folder. If you want to have the files in the same directory as the original file youll need to use: ```compileall -b```

Comment: As I mentioned in one of your other questions, the `VOLUME` statement prevents any future changes to that directory, and you should just delete it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, how can i create a read/write volume for manage it in this kind of fashion? so many thanks

Answer (score 4):

They are compiled, you will find your compiled files inside the `__pycache__` folder. If you want to have the files in the same directory as the original file youll need to use: `compileall -b`

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html):

> -b
>
> Write the byte-code files to their legacy locations and names, which may overwrite > byte-code files created by another version of Python. The default is to write files to > their PEP 3147 locations and names, which allows byte-code files from multiple > versions of Python to coexist.

Comment: even if i use -b (RUN python -m compileall -b ajaxfuncs/) no pyc file was created in the directory where .py are.

Comment: Did you see the comment from @David Maze, about your ```VOLUME``` statement?